# Rxjs: BehaviourSubject value emission

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a behaviour subject `BehaviorSubject<MyModel>(new MyModel)`. As per the readings done by me, I learned that whenever a subscription is done to behaviour subject, the subscriber gets a default `MyModel` object as soon as the subscription is done.

But I am confused on this scenario, suppose some `ClassA` subscribed on the behaviour subject and then emitted a value on the obsevrable after tweaking with it. After the `ClassA` has emitted, `ClassB` subscribes on the subject, so now does `ClassB`  on subscription receives the `new MyModel()` object or the model last emitted by the subject.

Please let me know if further clarification is required.

Comment: The last one emitted. `BehaviorSubject` immediately fires the most recently-emitted value on new subscriptions.

Comment: ^^ Note this is **not** true of Subjects in general, it refers specifically to `BehaviorSubject`. A `ReplaySubject`, for instance, immediately emits *all* previously-emitted values in sequence on new subscriptions.

Comment: I don't have a `ReplaySubject`, its a `BehaviourSubject`. I know how `ReplaySubject` works

Comment: Others might not - my comment is to them too :)

Comment: Any input on the actual doubt?

Comment: What are you still doubting, given my comment?

Comment: Okay got it, my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This started as a comment but turned into an answer:

In your scenario, the `ClassB` instance will get the `MyModel` instance emitted by your `ClassA` instance, *not* the one you created initially via `new MyModel()`.

In general, `BehaviorSubject` immediately fires the single most recently-emitted value on new subscriptions - this behavior is what defines a `BehaviorSubject` - versus, for instance, a `ReplaySubject` immediately emits *all* values that have been emitted so far on each new subscription.

Note this is easy to demonstrate empirically:

Comment: Note that you can initialize `ReplaySubject` with a buffer size: `new ReplaySubject<MyModel>(1)` will replay only the last value on subscription and behaves essentially like a `BehaviorSubject` that doesn't need an initial value.